# UNIX BASH: extracting number from string

Tags: string, bash, unix

This is probably a very simple question to an experienced person with UNIX however I'm trying to extract a number from a string and keep getting the wrong result.

This is the string:

```
8962 ? 00:01:09 java
```

This it the output I want

```
8962
```

But for some reason I  keep getting the same exact string back. This is what I've tried

```
pid=$(echo $str | sed "s/[^[0-9]{4}]//g")
```

If anybody could help me out it would be appreciated.

Comment: What if the PID isn't four digits?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is more than one way to skin a cat :

```
pti@pti-laptop:~$ echo 8962 ? 00:01:09 java | cut -d' ' -f1
8962
pti@pti-laptop:~$ echo 8962 ? 00:01:09 java | awk '{print $1}'
8962
```

cut cuts up a line in different fields based on a delimeter or just byte ranges and is often useful in these tasks.

awk is an older programming language especially useful for doing stuff one line at a time.

Answer (score 3):

Shell, no need to call external tools

```
$ s="8962 ? 00:01:09 java"
$ IFS="?"
$ set -- $s
$ echo $1
8962
```

Comment: No need to set `IFS="?"` since `set -- $s` will break on spaces.

Answer (score 3):

Pure Bash:

```
string='8962 ? 00:01:09 java'
pid=${string% \?*}
```

Or:

```
string='8962 ? 00:01:09 java'
array=($string)
pid=${array[0]}
```

Comment: You forgot `pid=${string%% *}`.

Comment: @Mark: True. And you forgot `pid=${string/ *}` ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you want:

```
pid=$(echo $str | sed 's/^\([0-9]\{4\}\).*/\1/')
```

Comment: I choose this answer because it stuck with using the sed command :p

Answer (score 2):

Pure Bash:

```
string="8962 ? 00:01:09 java"

[[ $string =~ ^([[:digit:]]{4}) ]]

pid=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
```

Answer (score 1):

`/^[0-9]{4}/`  matches 4 digits at the beginning of the string

Comment: Then OP should be more specific

Comment: It's safe to assume that "pid" implies 1-5 digits (on many systems).