# Checking That All Files Are Present

Tags: python, bash, csv, diff

I have a question about command line methods of searching. Here is my situation.

1. I have a data file which contains a bunch (~36,000) of objects' identification numbers, which looks like this:

   ```
   # ID
   85000213
   85000234
   85000246
   85000247
   85000249
   85000250
   ...
   ```
2. I also have a directory of datafiles which contain data about each object with names like:

   ```
   datafileID85000213.csv
   datafileID85000234.csv
   datafileID85000246.csv
   datafileID85000247.csv
   datafileID85000249.csv
   datafileID85000250.csv
   ...
   ```

I would actually like to check that all objects in my original ID datafile have an associated CSV file containing its actual data. My first idea for doing this is to use the diff command in order to compare these lists, but in order to do that I need to make a single column data file from the ~36,000 CSV filenames I have in order to compare to. One complication is that for most commands I have tried to use so far (mv, cp, ls), I get this:

> Argument list too long

Would anybody have a workaround (or a better idea) to this task?

For searching for the number in each filename string, there is one of two things I have found so far:

1. python:

   ```
   >>> import re
   >>> idlist
   ['abcdefg0.dat', 'abcdefg1.dat', 'abcdefg2.dat', 'abcdefg3.dat', 'abcdefg4.dat', 'abcdefg5.dat', 'abcdefg6.dat', 'abcdefg7.dat', 'abcdefg8.dat', 'abcdefg9.dat']
   >>> numbers = []
   >>> for i in range(len(idlist)):
   ...     numbers.append(re.search(r'\d+',idlist[i]).group())
   ... 
   >>> numbers
   ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
   ```
2. bash: [UNIX BASH: extracting number from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3569754/unix-bash-extracting-number-from-string)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Don't you have trouble with such a great number of files in a flat directory?

Comment: @SylvainLeroux - it will most certainly be slower than alternatives, but it will work.

Comment: @msw modern file-systems surely can handle such "large" number of files per directory. However I remember been bitten long time ago (on ... hum ... Win NT4) by the limited support for this in some tools (notably our incremental back-up utility). But maybe those days are gone too?

Comment: @ Sylvain Leroux - What exactly do you mean by "flat" directory?

Comment: @astromax: By "flat", Sylvain Leroux is referring to keeping all 36k files in a single directory, rather than having them split across some number of subdirectories.  Back In The Day (TM), some OSes and/or tools/programs/utilities would croak when working on directories with such large numbers of files.  This necessitated distributing such large numbers of files across multiple  sub-directories, each sub-directory having no more than (max limit) of files.

Comment: So, my operating system may be able to handle such a large flat directory, but is it the best option to handle such a large number of files (though they're only about 100 KB or so in size)? In terms of speedup, what are my alternatives (if this even makes sense to ask) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty easy in python:

```
import os.path
with open('idfile') as fin:
     header = next(fin) #read the `#ID` comment header line.  Don't use it.
     for line in fin:
         fname = 'datafileID{0}.csv'.format(line.strip())
         if not os.path.exists(fname):
             print fname
```

Comment: I will also give this a shot too once the data are done downloading - thanks for the speedy response!

Comment: What if the idfile and the directory where the csv files are contained are not the current directory? The idfile is easy, you just add the full path before it. But, should I be including the path in fname?

Comment: You could use something like:  `if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(path,fname)):`

Comment: Awesome! This worked for me. I had to be very careful with the directories where 'idfile' and the csv files live.

Answer (score 3):

From `bash`:

```
{
   # Read the header into a variable, but ignore it
   read -r hdrLine
   while read -r fileID; do
      [[ -f $DIRECTORY/datafileID$fileID.csv ]] || echo "$fileID not found"
   done
} < id_list.txt
```

Everything in `{...}` reads from the file `id_list.txt`. The first `read` statement reads and discards the header. The `while` loops then reads the remaining lines from the file, one at a time. With `DIRECTORY` set to the name of the directory where the files will live (or replaced with the hardcoded path, your choice), it checks if a file by the name of `datafileID$fileID.csv` exists in that directory. If so, nothing happens. Otherwise, a message to that effect is printed to standard output.

You can perform a more general check using a file glob.

```
[[ -f $DIRECTORY/*$fileID* ]]
```

would check if a file that contains `$fileID` anywhere in the name exists.

Comment: Excellent, as soon as my data is done downloading I will give this a shot!

Comment: I feel like using `test -f ... || echo ...` would be more explicit than `[[ ]]`, but I suppose it doesn't really matter.

Comment: It's the only non-POSIX part of the answer, so that would be a good reason to use `[` or `test` instead. But I prefer using `[[` when I can.

Comment: Hmm. I've tried this and it's telling me that none of the files exist, which can't be true. Can you explain what exactly is being done here? Also, eventually my files will have different names, but will still contain within it a string of numbers I'd like to extract. Is there a completely general way to search for that string of numbers within the filename without necessarily knowing the form of the filename beforehand? I think what I'm asking for is a way to search for regular expressions in bash.

Comment: Awesome, this worked perfectly for me! Thanks for the bash solution. A note to future readers - be careful about the directories which the files live in. The easiest thing to do is to change to it, print working directory, and copy it into the script or command line.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

```
import os
root = '/path/to/files/'
with open('filelist.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if not os.path.exists(root+'datafileID'+line.strip()+'.csv'):
            print line
```

This will print all the IDs that don't have matching files.

Comment: A good variant of the above solution. If it doesn't exist I will need to go back and download those ones anyway. Thanks!

Comment: Careful here, `line` will contain a trailing newline.

Comment: Good catch. Added strip() in there.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me with 40000 files:

```
diff <( ls -1 *.csv  | cut -c11-18 ) <( tail -n +2 idlist ) | grep '^>' | cut -d' ' -f2
```

The output is something like

```
80001234
80004321
```

Comment: Is the output ID numbers which are present, or ones which are absent?